# can I have the PATH variable evaluate to what directory I'm in?

Tags: bash, shell, path, command-line-interface

On `linux` using `bash`,
lets say I made two programs both called `print_report`.
(They are in different directories.)

Inside my `.bashrc` file, I have:

> PATH="path/to/print_report1/:$PATH"

This allows me to type `print_report` anywhere and it will run one of the programs.

---

**How can I have bash decide to use one or the other depending on the working directory?**

for example,
If I'm currently in `~/project1/` and type `print_report` it will use `/bin/foo/print_report`
If I'm currently in `~/project2/` and type `print_report` it will use `/bin/bar/print_report`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that as such. Instead, write a wrapper script or function that checks the current directory and invokes the right command:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $PWD == $HOME/project1/* ]]
then
    /bin/foo/print_report "$@"
elif [[ $PWD == $HOME/project2/* ]] 
then
    /bin/bar/print_report "$@"
else
    echo "Don't know how to print_report for $PWD"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a security disaster waiting to happen, (which is to say you really don't want to do this) but you can certainly do something like:

```
cd() {
    dir=${1-.}
    case $dir in)
        path1) PATH=/path/for/working/in/path1;;
        path2) PATH=/path/for/working/in/path2;;
        *) PATH=/bin:/usr/bin;;
    esac
    command cd $dir
}
```

(Put that in your .bashrc or just define it in the current shell.)

Comment: Virtual +1 for noting the security implications

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate [preexec hooks](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) à la zsh, using the DEBUG trap.

In that way, every time a command is executed, you can run a preexec hook to check $PWD, and adjust $PATH accordingly.

You can include a preexec hook doing what you want in your .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Everything presented here so far strikes me as overly complicated and needlessly complex hackery. I would just place a `Makefile` in each directory with

```
report:
        /bin/foo/print_report
```

in `~/project1/Makefile`, and

```
report:
        /bin/bar/print_report
```

in `~/project2/Makefile`. This extends easily to as many directories and programs you want. And you only need to type `make` instead of those longwinded command names :-)